# What happens with the empty set in the categorical definition of a presheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I've found in Hartshorne's book on Algebraic Geometry a categorical definition of a presheaf (Ch. 2.1, just after the first definition). He there defines for a topological space $X$ the category $\mathfrak{Top}(X)$, whose objects are the open sets of $X$ and the only morphisms are the inclusion maps.

But what is the inclusion from the object $\emptyset$ to any other object in $\mathfrak{Top}(X)$? Can I even define a function on an empty domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, the empty set is the initial set: there's exactly one map to any other set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definition is formal, it is not a function from $U$ to $V$.

If $U$ is included in $V$, we **set** $$Hom(U,V) = \{pt\},$$ where $\{pt\}$ is a set with one element. This $\{pt\}$ is not an application or the inclusion $U \to V$ this is just a formal way to say "if $U$ is in $V$, draw an arrow". Hence, because the empty set is included in every open set, you can draw an arrow from the empty set to each object and it is an initial object in this category.

Answer (score 2):

Your question whether one can define a function with empty domain is  irrelevant and probably results from some misunderstanding.
For example on any topological  space $X$ we can define the  constant presheaf $\mathcal Z$ associating to any open subset $U\subset X$ **empty or not** the set $\mathbb Z$, and to any inclusion $V\hookrightarrow U$ the identity map $$f_{VU}=Id_\mathbb Z:\mathcal Z(U)=\mathbb Z\to \mathcal Z(V)=\mathbb Z:z\mapsto z.$$ Nowhere are functions with empty domain involved: the maps $$f_{\emptyset U}=Id_\mathbb Z:\mathcal Z(U)=\mathbb Z\to \mathcal Z(\emptyset)=\mathbb Z:z\mapsto z .$$ are quite down-to-earth maps with domain $\mathbb Z$, a comfortably non-empty set!

This presheaf is not a sheaf: its associated sheaf satisfies $\mathcal F^+(\emptyset )=\{\star\}$, a singleton set different from $\mathcal F(\emptyset)=\mathbb Z$ but nevertheless again non-empty.
[If $U\subset X$ is a non-empty open subset the set $\mathcal F^+(U)$ consists in locally constant functions $U\to \mathbb Z$]

As you see no function with empty domain appeared above and the same is true for all (pre)sheaves encountered in practice.